# How can I get and parse Json from URL?

Tags: android, json

`JSON` structure is

```
[
   ["Sonstiges"],
   ["Unterhaltung"],
   ["Serie"]
   ["Spielfilm"],
   ["Report"],
   ["Sport"],
   ["Kinder"]
]
```

Comment: Source: http://5.39.219.67/~tvinfo/tvguide/box/getgenrelist?mediagroupId=9c476522-d771-4fcd-ae21-34b302c04e46

Comment: Hey Ricky. I think you're going to have to put a little more effort into this. What have you tried?

Comment: There's not a lot of info in your question, but Android has org.json built in, and for a stream-based approach you can use GSON or Jackson.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[You can use this handy library for same](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http)..

Comment: how this is related to "question" (aside from quality of the question)?

Comment: This library lets u do Async Http request and gives you parsed Json object..thats what the question is all about..

Comment: to parse string into json you do not need anything external. built-in JSON support is working fine: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct..i mentioned this lib because question also involve getting it from URL..

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.